# how to display the raw angular expressions without having them evaluated angularJS

Tags: angularjs

here i am trying to display the expressions as it is `{{x}}*{{y()}}:`
But it is evaluated always.i have checked across the portal for possible answers and found none.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/divm/ajenauxz/5/) is a JSFiddle to illustrate the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ng-non-bindable` directive.

This directive prevents the compilation of inner elements.

**Markup**

`<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCntrl">
    <code ng-non-bindable>{{x}}*{{y()}}:</code> {{x}}*{{y()}}
</body>`

More on this at: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngNonBindable